# Problem to serialize and deserealize Geom field Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate-spatial

I have a exception `Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize` and another exception `Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 30313031` My class definition is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "puente_22", schema = "transporte")
public class Puente implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuidpuente")
    //@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    @Convert(converter = UUIDConverter.class)
    private UUID uuidpuente = UUID.randomUUID();
    
    
    
    private String codp;
    
    private String nombre;
    
    private String rioque;
    
    private Double galibo;
    
    private Double ancho;
    
    private Double x;
    
    private Double y;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="puente", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ItemIntervencion>itemIntervencion;
    
    
    //@JsonSerialize(using = PointToJsonSerializer.class)
    //@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonToPointDeserializer.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,32718)")
    private Point geom;
    
    
    //@JsonIgnore
    
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Proyecto proy;
```

Proyecto entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "proyipuent", schema = "transporte")
public class Proyecto implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long idproypuent;
    
    private String namproy;
    
    private Double invtot;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Anio  anio;
    
    private String consedoc;
    
    private Integer num_fam_benef;
    
    private Date fec_in_obra;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Modalidad modalidad;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private EstadoProy estadoproy;
    
    //@JsonIgnore
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proy", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Puente> puentes;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="proy",fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Intervencion>intervenciones;
```

I am using `import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;`
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded from a previous version of Hibernate, you need to switch the JTS library from `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point` to `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point` and use the accompanying library in your gradle or maven as well: `org.locationtech.jts:jts-core`

I ran into the same issue when upgrading to spring boot 3, as Hibernate gets upgraded as well.

More info on the spatial migration can be found in this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59270817